# How to keep google Oauth token permanently without publishing the application

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

I needed to write an automation as I need to retrieve my events from a third party application to my google calendar. Google Calender has option to add calendar from url but I need it to sync instantly and have it cooler separated based on the type of event. Now I've the application it's used by only two people but It can not be set as an internal application as the need of syncing data to personal email as that's what's signed in everywhere. Now google requires me publish the app so my tokens stop expiring which is a problem is there a way to work around this or I've to go through the hassle of publishing the application and complete the process of this so this automation can be used.